# problem with open popup onclick marker in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup

I am very new to openlayers. I have done showing map and whenever we click on the map it is showing marker. But i need to open the popup when i click on the marker.

The following code has some problem. When i click on marker popup is displaying but at the corner it is displaying. I want to display the popup on the marker it self

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );

    var zoom=16;
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
   var opx = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy) ;
   var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(opx);
   markers.addMarker(marker);
   marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
   popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
                   map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy),
                   new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                   "example popup",
                   true);

map.addPopup(popup);
  }); 
});

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                         marker.lonlat,
                         new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                         "example popup",
                         null, true);
```

[image]